Webpack-bundle-analyzer does not show chunks in the left side panel
A minor question that I can not get the answer for in any sources. I will describe the situation:
Basically, wanted to play around with webpack-bundle-analyzer and everything is pretty straight forward:

Created a template React app with CRA
Installed couple common 3rd party packages (just to see how they affect prod bundle size)
3. Removed web-vitals package
Installed craco to adust the webpack config without ejecting
Ran the webpack bundle analyzer.

Code snippets for the important points:
4.
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = function () {
  return {
    webpack: {
      plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: "server" })],
    },
  };
};




"analyze": "craco build"
The problem:
I was expecting to see the "Show chunks" in the left side bar, that would list all the bundled files and their sizes, but I dont see them:

It is very odd, but if I add back the web-vitals package and run the webpack-bundle-analyzer, then I see the "Show chunks" list. Also I tried this back and fourth - removed the package, which resulted in not seeing the "Show chunks" and then added back again, which resulted in seeing the "Show chunks". Also I see, that now the blocks are in different color, so it looks like it is doing something, maybe like there is some load speed scale.:

Why I am removing the package
I am used to working with analytics/monitoring tools like Sentry and Datadog and this web-vitals package is something, that I would not really need, since these tools allow to get all the same stuff, like "First Contentful Paint (FCP)", "Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)" etc.
So now I am not sure, how is web-vitals a vital package for webpack-bundle-analyzer, because its not mentioned anywhere or maybe I have missed it in the docs.
